how to use InCallService as default phone app in MAUI in Android
I need to control audio device when answering call and be able to automatically answer incoming calls. There is sample ready one application in android which handle incoming call dialog instead of default phone app. So using it I can control speaker.
The functionality is based on InCallService.
I am looking for MAUI implementation of InCallService.

Refer to this case: .NET MAUI How to implement CallScreeningService?

it is different service and different implementation

Well, I find this: Build a calling app. It's about implementation of android native. wish it can help you.

its similar to example I shared, BUT how to do it in MAUI?

You can create a Xamarin native project(Xamarin Android project), use something similar to Android native (Activity/xml/AndroidManifest...)  to achieve a calling app. Then migrate to MAUI.

it is very complicated task. I found very simple Android java application https://github.com/jewom/simple-phone/tree/master  - maybe you can make it MAUI?

any chance to get working sample?
